# Need help calling function from header file

Tags: c

I have a header file called "ChessMoves.h" and a c file call ChessMoves with a bunch of different functions.

Header file

```
#ifndef __CHESSMOVES_H
#define __CHESSMOVES_H

typedef struct Location
{
    // the square's column ('a' through 'h')
    char col;

    // the square's row (1 through 8)
    int row;
} Location;

typedef struct Move
{
    // location where this piece is moving from
    Location from_loc;

    // location where this piece is moving to
    Location to_loc;

    // what type of chess piece is being moved
    char piece;

    // whether this move captures another piece
    short int isCapture;

    // the color of the piece being moved
    Color color;
} Move;
```

File I'm calling to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ChessMoves.h"

void parseNotationString(char *str, Move *whiteMove, Move *blackMove){

    int i, space = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    int white[10], black[10], move[10], to[2];

    whiteMove.color = WHITE;
    if(white[0] > 64)
        whiteMove.piece = white[0];
    if(white[0] < 64)
        whiteMove.from_loc.row = white[0];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if(white[i] == 'x')
            whiteMove.isCapture = 1;
    for(i = 0; j < 10; i++)
        if(white[i] == ' ')
            to[0] = white[i-2];
            to[1] = white[i-1];

    printf("%c %c", to[0], to[0]);
}
```

We were given a file to test the code and in that file he has:

```
whiteMove.color != WHITE
```

and if whiteMove.color does not equal WHITE it will display "FAIL" so I tried 
setting

```
whiteMove.color = WHITE
```

but I keep getting "request for member 'color' in something not a structure or union. The same thing goes for the other structs I try to call. I tried making it,

```
Move.color = WHITE
```

and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Why are you testing uninitialized `white[0]` ?

Comment: None of the syntax is C, given the lack of semicolons.

Comment: whiteMove.color = WHITE; should be whiteMove->color; It's a pointer.

Comment: Since `whiteMove` and `blackMove` are both pointers, you need to either use the `->` operator (`whiteMove->color`) or dereference the pointer before applying the `.` operator (`(*blackMove).color`).

Comment: You have a bug in that last `if` statement. And now you know why braces are good style. :)

Comment: Your include guard `__CHESSMOVES_H` is an identifier reserved for use by the Implementor. A compiler writer is permitted to use such identifiers (beginning with an underscore followed by another underscore or an uppercase letter) for any purpose, and if they do then your code will fall down go boom. You would be better served by using, for example, `CHESSMOVES_H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can have something that compiles I've put this all into a file, chopped off the irrelevant bits, and added the missing `Color` enum.

```
$ cat test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { WHITE, BLACK } Color;

typedef struct Location
{
    // the square's column ('a' through 'h')
    char col;

    // the square's row (1 through 8)
    int row;
} Location;

typedef struct Move
{
    // location where this piece is moving from
    Location from_loc;

    // location where this piece is moving to
    Location to_loc;

    // what type of chess piece is being moved
    char piece;

    // whether this move captures another piece
    short int isCapture;

    // the color of the piece being moved
    Color color;
} Move;


void parseNotationString(char *str, Move *whiteMove, Move *blackMove){

    int i, space = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    int white[10], black[10], move[10], to[2];

    whiteMove.color = WHITE;

    if(white[0]>64)
        whiteMove.piece = white[0];
    if(white[0]<64)
        whiteMove.from_loc.row = white[0];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        if(white[i] == 'x')
            whiteMove.isCapture = 1;
    for(i=0;j<10;i++)
        if(white[i] == ' ')
            to[0] = white[i-2];
            to[1] = white[i-1];

    printf("%c %c", to[0], to[0]);
}
```

Compiling it with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) gives the answer immediately.

```
$ make
cc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:40:14: error: member reference type 'Move *' (aka 'struct Move *') is a pointer; did you mean
      to use '->'?
    whiteMove.color = WHITE;
    ~~~~~~~~~^
             ->
test.c:43:18: error: member reference type 'Move *' (aka 'struct Move *') is a pointer; did you mean
      to use '->'?
        whiteMove.piece = white[0];
        ~~~~~~~~~^
                 ->
test.c:45:18: error: member reference type 'Move *' (aka 'struct Move *') is a pointer; did you mean
      to use '->'?
        whiteMove.from_loc.row = white[0];
        ~~~~~~~~~^
                 ->
test.c:48:22: error: member reference type 'Move *' (aka 'struct Move *') is a pointer; did you mean
      to use '->'?
            whiteMove.isCapture = 1;
            ~~~~~~~~~^
                     ->
4 errors generated.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

`whiteMove` is a `Move *`, a pointer to a `Move` structure. As such it has to be dereferenced with `->`. `.` is for direct access.

clang's error messages are excellent and even give you a suggestion how to fix it. I would strongly suggest you use it, or compiler with similarly good errors, while learning C.

---

Furthermore your code has a subtle bug.

```
    for(i=0;j<10;i++)
        if(white[i] == ' ')
            to[0] = white[i-2];
            to[1] = white[i-1];
```

This does not do what the indentation says it does. It's actually this.

```
    for(i=0;j<10;i++)
        if(white[i] == ' ')
            to[0] = white[i-2];

    to[1] = white[i-1];
```

And this is why we [***always use braces***](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no#16530).